# Ios4 not quitting my program, it just pause and minimize it

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone sdk . I am writing a program and I want it to totally quit whenever the player press the home button. I am using my iPhone (IOS4) to test. When I press the home button on iPhone while my app is running, it does't really quit the app. Is there any way to fix it so that every time I launch my app, it start newly. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks a lot .

Tony

Answer (score 4):

Set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in `Info.plist` to `YES`, and you're all set.